# Reading input and printing specific output

Tags: c, input, output

I wish to write a program in C that reads input and only prints certain output (in particular, it omits comments).

> Clarification: I would like it to behave exactly like a C processor. I believe C processors replace comments with spaces, so once I detect the end of a comment, I can just replace it with a space.
>
> This means that this program should properly deal with trigraphs, escaped quotes, and other things that might affect comments.

The function ignores any comment characters in its input. For instance, except for input within strings, it ignores all input in the form of a C comment (e.g., input between `/*` and `*/` and between `//` and a newline (`\n`) character).

Note that in the second case, the newline character is printed whereas in the first case, neither `/*` nor `*/` are printed.

Within a string, however (e.g. `"hello //world"`), the program will print whatever comes after the comment specifiers (in this case, it would print `"hello //world"` even though "world" is preceded by a single-line C-comment specifier).

So far, I have tried to consider several cases. I have considered defining two variables `sngl_line` and `multi_line` to determine when input is between a // and a \n (i.e., sngl_line is true) or when input is between `/*` and `*/` (i.e., multi_line is true).
I have written a program that ignores comments outside of strings, but I find dealing with trigraphs especially problematic. Perhaps I should deal with them later?

> I would also like my program to produce errors (e.g., if there is a nonterminating double quote or comment, it prints an appropriate error message).
> Note: I have successfully written a program that ignores comments as expected (except maybe not when trigraphs are present in strings). So I do not wish to see any working C code; just a few general tips as to how to produce the right errors will suffice.

Comment: There are numerous questions with answers about deleting comments in C code.  Note that `'//'` does not start a comment either.  Beware backlash-newline at the end of a line of a 'single-line' comment.  Beware backslash-newline in the middle of `/*`, `*/` or `//`.  Also note that the compiler replaces a comment by a blank (space).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Have you checked out he C pre-processor?

Comment: @AdrianCornish Sometimes the best way of learning is to re-invent a pre-existing wheel. If the OP hasn't used state-machines before, this will be a good exercise for learning about them.

Comment: @TripeHound Fair point, but also new coders waste millions of man hours doing what has been done.

Comment: @AdrianCornish New coders will never become _good_ old coders if all they do is join other people's libraries together. _Someone_ has to be good enough to write the new libraries!

Comment: @TripeHound Lol - Bullshite - if that was true we wouldn't have libc

Comment: @AdrianCornish "Why reinvent the wheel?"  Agree, the wheels of my car are [rock solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones) . ;-)

Comment: Dan Are you looking for someone to post working C code?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no thanks. I already have (mostly) working C code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Process the input as if your are in one of the following states:

1. Normal
2. Inside ""
3. Inside ''
4. Inside a /* */ comment
5. Inside a // end-of-line comment

From each state there are a few rules of how to transition to another state.

E.g. From // comment state, stay there until end of line, then go to normal.
From *normal*, if next characters are `//`, jump to // comment state.
From *normal*, if next characters are `/*`, jump to /* comment state.

It is really a most rewarding programming task so I won't list more.

---

It looks like OP's data does not exercise the '' state.

Comment: You will also want to track having just seen a backslash ("\"), which may not necessarily be a state (or set of states) in itself, but could modify how the next character transitions to a new state or not. Also, there's a state 3a. that is "having seen `/`" (which, depending on the _next_ character, might transition to 3., 4. or 1.

Comment: @TripeHound The _states_ I proposed are of indefinite length.   In general,  backslash escape, `/*`, `*/`, `//` are short finite (except pesky hex) and can be analyzed as a token or not to the next state.  True one could create many minor states - I just handle those little ones as token decoding.

Comment: @TripeHound Where do you get th idea that backslash is a special character here?

Comment: @hyde example: in the `""` state, a backslash  " does not end the state.  Even though OP's data set does not use it - so potentially ignorable for this data - but not in general.

Comment: @chux I can't find that in the question text.

Comment: @hyde to clarify things, I want my program to work just how a C preprocessor ignores comments. I would like to deal with all special cases (e.g., escaped quotes).

Comment: @Dan.  Re-trigraphs:  Recommend to code a solution without them.  It is not too hard to handle that later.   A central issue is that code can not only `get` characters from `FILE*`, but also `unget` them too.  Like when trying to determine if  `/` is followed by `/, *, other`, the _other_ should be un-gotten..